# How Can I Create a Front Page Based on Blocks?

Tags: views

I am building a front page that comprises a number of Views-based blocks.  How can I create a front page that has no actual "content" (besides these blocks) without getting a "Page not found error"?

The best I have been able to do is create a Views page and set a filter that will never return a result e.g. nid < 0.  I set the path to the front page and the title to none.  This seems like unnecessary overhead.

Surely, there must be a better way?

Answer (score 2):

If it was me, I would create a custom page-front.tpl.  I'd omit the $content region and probably create a few custom regions for the homepage.  I can then place my blocks into the regions.

D6 create page-front.tpl.php
D7 create page--front.tpl.php

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure that solves the problem.  The title tag still shows page not found.  I would probably have to use a preprocessor function to get around this.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) and [Ctools Page Manager](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) to create a page and populate it with blocks or other content. You can use one of the built-in layouts, create your own, or use one from [Panels Extra Layouts](http://drupal.org/project/panels_extra_layouts)

Once you've built your page, you can then assign its path to the site's front page.

Comment: So far, I have been trying to stick to Context but I may have to throw in towel at some point and switch to Panels.

Answer (score 0):

[Front Page](http://drupal.org/project/front) module is supposed to solve problems like yours:

> The Front Page module allows for customised home pages dependant on role. The pages can be of the following types:
>
> - **Alias** (only 2.x branch) - Allows for another Drupal path to be shown as the home page without redirecting the user.
> - Redirect - Allows you to redirect users to a local or remote URL.
> - Themed - Allows you to enter some static text that will be placed into the content area of a standard Drupal page.
> - Full - Allows for static content to be displayed to the screen as is. This method does not pass through Drupal's theming system.

Alias should be most interesting for you.

Comment: Not sure this is what I need.  It still requires me to alias the front page to another path.

Comment: And under that path you can have whatever you want, without dealing with default frontpage code. It allows you a clean start - to build new front page from scratch, using whatever means you want, be it Simple Page node, Views page, page created by your custom module...

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

- Create a new content type called "Homepage"
- Edit the default display of the content type to hide what you want (e.g. Body).
- Create a Homepage node and point front page to it in admin settings.
- Add blocks to their respective regions (you could also use a grid system like Zen Grids which comes with Zen, this is what I do<sup>1</sup>)
- You can override page--node--homepage.tpl.php to do stuff like removing the title, or any extra control you want over it.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> A grid system is a really nice way to control the position of elements on your site. Generally I use regions to control the vertical order of elements, and then the grid to position horizontally.</sub>

Comment: Thanks.  I don't think a front page merits its own content type (at least in my own case as I don't have the need for multiple front pages).  I am using Zen (and ZenGrids) but the issue is that of the path.

Comment: The Homepage content type isn't so that you can create multiple homepages (after all, you can only point the front page at one), it's about decoupling it from a standard page content type so that you have control over it without ruining your page content type. What's the issue with the path?